# Attach source to jar library in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I use custom library `mylib.jar` that is not built with Maven to Eclipse Maven Java project.:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>caen</groupId>
        <artifactId>CAENRFIDLibrary</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}${file.separator}..${file.separator}mylib.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But how to tell system where is source code located of current library in order Eclipse could find it? Is it might be configured through Maven or I should tell about it directly to Eclipse via `Java Source Attachment`?

[image]

UPD

Installing library to local jar repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Projects\eclipse_ide_workspace\CAENRFIDLibrary.jar" -DgroupId=caen  -DartifactId=CAENRFIDLibrary -Dversion=1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Got output that looks nice:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Projects\eclipse_ide_workspace\CAENRFIDLibrary.jar to C:\Users\vico\.m2\repository\caen\CAENRFIDLibrary\1\CAENRFIDLibrary-1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.472 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-17T11:45:41+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Trying to add it to my project `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>caen</groupId>
    <artifactId>CAENRFIDLibrary</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Eclipse pom.xml editor complains regarding library

```
Missing artifact caen:CAENRFIDLibrary:jar:1.0
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: First using system scope dependencies is deprecated furthermore better start using a repository manage and upload the jar as well as the source package into that and afterwards you can add it as a usual dependencies...

Comment: I was trying to upload library to repository, but can't use it. More details in question body UPD. And how I can upload source zip file there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option would be to install the custom jar to your local maven repository. Please see the below documentation

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: And how to attach source of this library?

Comment: I was trying to upload library to repository, but can't use it. More details in question body UPD.

Comment: When you installed in to maven repo, you used version ‘1’. But when you refer it in pom, you are using version ‘1.0’. Please ensure to use same version that exists in maven repo.